# Frequent reference to application variables in all sessions

Tags: asp-classic

Could a professional who understands this subject to answer my question please?

I working with classic ASP and sorry if my question seems to be trivial but I don’t understand about the overhead of referencing application variables repeatedly for reading and not for modifying.

I have declared a global application level variable that caches large strings and other arrays.

In sessionOntart I assign the application variable to a session variable. Then on each page I assign the session variable to a local variable to avoid using the session variable repeatedly.

My question is could I just use the application variable directly and repeatedly on every page in every session or does this create a problem?
In other words, consider the following two scenarios:

SCENARIO 1:

--In applicationOnStart:

Application(“globalArray”)  = a large array of thousands of string and array  elements

--In sessionOnStart:

Session(“globalArray”)  = Application(“globalArray”)

--On every page of the website:

Dim anArray
anArray =  session(“globalArray”)
Now use the anArray as many times as needed.

SENARIO 2:

--In applicationOnStart:

Application(“globalArray”)  = a large array of thousands of string and array  elements

--On every page of the website use Application(“globalArray”)  as many times as needed.

My question: Considering a busy web traffic, is scenario 2 better or scenario 1?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I can definitively answer this question with the information provided, but I will comment that logically speaking, scenario #1 sounds inefficient and doesn't seem to serve a practical purpose unless each user needs their own unique globalArray with different values in it, or unless the Application variable is changing often and you only want to grab new copies of it for the user only at specific times later.

It sounds like if you initialize this array in ApplicationStart and you create a copy of it in SessionStart every time a user logs in, that you probably aren't changing the values at any other point. If my understanding is correct then I would favor scenario #2 to reduce unnecessary memory consumption.

For example, if you have 1000 users log in, do you actually need 1000 unique copies of this large array in memory (scenario #1) or only one copy of it (scenario #2)?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The answer is there is no need for unique copies of the array for each user. I just need to understand if it is ok to liberally use the application variable many times in each session. So What I understand from your writing is that there is no overhead with using the application variable as often as needed for accessing its content. Do you confirm this?

Comment: @Dave123 basically, yes. There would be considerably more overhead in having hundreds or thousands of copies of the same object in memory compared to having only one central copy of the object. If the object can change however, then having one copy shared by many users could present concurrency problems, but as I understand you, this object is read-only so you're better off with only one copy of it in memory.

Comment: Thank you again for your reply. I appreciate it. If you don't mind I ask this related question There is this Miicrosoft tips page at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972335.aspx#asptips_topic4
Under tip2, the paragraph before last says: "it would be much better to build a custom component with a custom method to store the weather stations".
This information is a vague to me. Do you think that they mean to get the stations for example from database then loop and assign each to an array element. And then access the array by the com methods to use less memory?

Comment: @Dave123 I suggest that you should not ask a new question in the comments section of an existing question. It would be better to ask a totally new question which will attract new views and new answers. Also, if my answer helped you, please mark it as an accepted answer or at the very least up-vote it.